# postgresql: datatype numeric with limited digits

Tags: postgresql, types, numeric

I am looking for numeric datatype with limited digits
(before and after the decimal point)

The function kills only digits after the decimal point. (PG version >= 13)

```
create function num_flex( v numeric, d int) returns numeric as 
$$
  select case when v=0 then 0 
              when v  < 1 and  v > -1  then trim_scale(round(v, d - 1 ) )
              else trim_scale(round(v, d - 1 - least(log(abs(v))::int,d-1) ) ) end;
$$
language sql ;
```

For testing:

```
select num_flex( 0, 6) 
union all
select num_flex( 1.22000, 6) 
union all
select num_flex( (-0.000000123456789*10^x)::numeric,6) 
from generate_series(1,15,3) t(x) 
union all
select num_flex( (0.0000123456789*10^x)::numeric,6) 
from generate_series(1,15,3) t(x) ;
```

It runs,
but have someone a better idea or find a bug (a situation, that is not implemented)?

The next step is to integrate this in PG, so that I can write

```
select 12.123456789::num_flex6 ; 
select 12.123456789::num_flex7 ;
```

for a num_flex datatype with 6 or 7 digits.
with types from num_flex2 to num_flex9. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just use `numeric(x,y)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Turns out you commented that faster than I could post my answer. On second thought, one reason I can think of is when you really want to keep  a fixed number of digits, regardless of the scale, or the side of decimal point. `numeric(n)` is actually `numeric(n,0)`, which is dictated by the SQL standard. If you want to have 12345.0 as well as 0.12345, there's no way you can configure `numeric` to hold both. `numeric(5)` will round 0.12345 to 0, `numeric(5,5)` will dedicate all digits to the right of decimal point and reject 12345.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your function:

1. Accepting negative digit counts (parameter `d`). `num_flex(1234,-2)` returns `1200` - you specified you want the function to only kill digits after decimal point, so `1234` would be expected.
2. Incorrect results between -1 and 1. `num_flex(0.123,3)` returns `0.12` instead of `0.123`. I guess this might also be desired effect if you do want to count 0 to the left of decimal point. Normally, that `0` is ignored when a number's precision and scale are considered.
3. Your counting of digits to the left of decimal point is incorrect due to how `::int` rounding works. `log(abs(11))::int` is `1` but `log(abs(51))::int` is `2`. `ceil(log(abs(v)))::int` returns `2` in both cases, while keeping `int` type to still work as 2nd parameter in `round()`.

```sql
create or replace function num_flex( 
    input_number numeric,
    digit_count int,
    is_counting_unit_zero boolean default false)
returns numeric as 
$$
  select trim_scale(
            case 
                when input_number=0 
                    then 0 
                when digit_count<=0 --avoids negative rounding
                    then round(input_number,0)
                when (input_number between -1 and 1) and is_counting_unit_zero
                    then round(input_number,digit_count-1)
                when (input_number between -1 and 1)
                    then round(input_number,digit_count)
                else 
                    round(  input_number, 
                            greatest( --avoids negative rounding
                                digit_count - (ceil(log(abs(input_number))))::int,
                                0)
                    )
            end
          );
$$
language sql;
```

Here's a test

```sql
select *,"result"="should_be"::numeric as "is_correct" from 
(values
    ('num_flex(0.1234      ,4)',num_flex(0.1234      ,4), '0.1234'),
    ('num_flex(1.234       ,4)',num_flex(1.234       ,4), '1.234'),
    ('num_flex(1.2340000   ,4)',num_flex(1.2340000   ,4), '1.234'),
    ('num_flex(0001.234    ,4)',num_flex(0001.234    ,4), '1.234'),
    ('num_flex(123456      ,5)',num_flex(123456      ,5), '123456'),
    ('num_flex(0           ,5)',num_flex(0           ,5), '0'),
    ('num_flex(00000.00000 ,5)',num_flex(00000.00000 ,5), '0'),
    ('num_flex(00000.00001 ,5)',num_flex(00000.00001 ,5), '0.00001'),
    ('num_flex(12345678901 ,5)',num_flex(12345678901 ,5), '12345678901'),
    ('num_flex(123456789.1 ,5)',num_flex(123456789.1 ,5), '123456789'),
    ('num_flex(1.234      ,-4)',num_flex(1.234       ,4), '1.234')
) as t ("operation","result","should_be");
--        operation         |   result    |  should_be  | is_correct
----------------------------+-------------+-------------+------------
-- num_flex(0.1234      ,4) |      0.1234 | 0.1234      | t
-- num_flex(1.234       ,4) |       1.234 | 1.234       | t
-- num_flex(1.2340000   ,4) |       1.234 | 1.234       | t
-- num_flex(0001.234    ,4) |       1.234 | 1.234       | t
-- num_flex(123456      ,5) |      123456 | 123456      | t
-- num_flex(0           ,5) |           0 | 0           | t
-- num_flex(00000.00000 ,5) |           0 | 0           | t
-- num_flex(00000.00001 ,5) |     0.00001 | 0.00001     | t
-- num_flex(12345678901 ,5) | 12345678901 | 12345678901 | t
-- num_flex(123456789.1 ,5) |   123456789 | 123456789   | t
-- num_flex(1.234      ,-4) |       1.234 | 1.234       | t
--(11 rows)
```

You can declare the `precision` (total number of digits) of your `numeric` data type in the [column definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html#:%7E:text=The%20precision%20of,scale%20of%20zero.). Only digits after decimal point will be rounded. If there are too many digits before the decimal point, you'll get an error.

The downside is that `numeric(n)` is actually `numeric(n,0)`, which is dictated by the SQL standard. So if by limiting the column's number of digits to `5` you want to have `12345.0` as well as `0.12345`, there's no way you can configure `numeric` to hold both. `numeric(5)` will round `0.12345` to `0`, `numeric(5,5)` will dedicate all digits to the right of decimal point and reject `12345`.

```sql
create table test (numeric_column numeric(5));
insert into test values (12345.123);
table test;
-- numeric_column
------------------
--          12345
--(1 row)

insert into test values (123456.123);
--ERROR:  numeric field overflow
--DETAIL:  A field with precision 5, scale 0 must round to an absolute value less than 10^5.
```